# Map null using ValueInjecter

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

How do I map a null to an object using valueinjecter? It throws an error when I do this.

Do I need to use something else other than `InjectFrom()`?

**more info**

I have a repository that returns an object domain. I then want to map this domain to a viewmodel. The repository will return null if the object doesn't exist. I cannot map a null object to the viewmodel. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve, source.InjectFrom(null), are you trying to set all properties to null or default values or ... ???

Comment: @omu edited, I want to assign the whole source object to null if the parameter is null.

Answer (score 0):

for your scenario usually I would throw an error that the user tries to edit an entity that doesn't exist, but anyway, you could do it like this:

```
var o = repo.get(7);
var vm = new ViewModel();

if (o != null) vm.InjectFrom(o);
```

or

```
vm.InjectFrom(o ?? new Entity());
```